# Calling a Dictionary and its Variables from Another Module in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a dictionary stored in one module (Module6):

```
Sub WebcamDict() 


    Dim dict As Object, Key, val 
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 


    Key = "14 Mile Hill North": val = Array("URL", "Title") 
    dict.Add Key, val 
    Key = "14 Mile Hill South": val = Array("URL", "Title") 
    dict.Add Key, val 
    Key = "Ash Fork East": val = Array("URL", "Title") 
    dict.Add Key, val 
    ... 

End Sub
```

In a different module I am trying to call the dictionary and its variables like this:

```
Sub Images() 
    Call Module6.WebcamDict 

    ComboBoxList = Array(CStr(ComboBox4), CStr(ComboBox5), CStr(ComboBox6), CStr(ComboBox7)) 


    i = 1 


    For Each Ky In ComboBoxList 
        ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Webcam" & CStr(i)).Fill.UserPicture (dict.Item(Ky)(0)) 
        ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Webcam" & CStr(i)).TextFrame.DeleteText 
        ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Webcam" & CStr(i)).Line.Visible = msoFalse 
        ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Webcam" & CStr(i) & "_Text").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = dict.Item(Ky)(1) 


        i = i + 1 


    Next 


    Set dict = Nothing 


End Sub
```

The variable "i" and "Ky" both seem to work fine as tested by
`Debug.Print` statements. However, I get the error (Object Required) for this line:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Webcam" & CStr(i)).Fill.UserPicture (dict.Item(Ky)(0))
```

If I just include the dictionary in the same module it works perfectly, but I will need to call this from multiple different modules, so I will need to be able to call it along with its variables somehow. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Dim dict As Object` from the sub (keeping everything else as is). At the top of the module put the line

```
Public dict As Object
```

This will turn `dict` into a global variable which is accessible anywhere in the project. In your current code it is a local variable which goes out of scope when `WebCamdict` returns.